# Как убрать 500 ошибки и включить ошибки PHP.

Tags: apache

В php.ini включил display_errors и display_startup_errors, не помогло.

Comment: До того как вы не исправите ошибку 500, PHP вам не видать. Это ошибка сервера, и почему она может возникать очень легко нагуглить.

Comment: Ты вообще о чем... У нас любая ошибка фатальная или парсинга PHP вызывает 500-ю ошибку. Как ее отключить и включить ошибки самого PHP?

Comment: Откуда я могу знать, что там **у вас** по той скудной информации, что ты предоставил? PHP работает как CGI (если да, то читаем error.log как сказал @gurzufnet)?

Comment: В `.htaccess` прописать `php_flag display_errors 1`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17693462/4223982 ... По крайней мере мне помогло ...

Answer (score 5):

пробовали в начале скрипта прописать

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Отчего возникает ошибка 500 (Internal Server Error)?](http://www.jino.ru/support/faq/problems/error-500.html#error-500)

> Наиболее частой причиной ошибки 500 (Internal Server Error, внутренняя ошибка сервера) является неверный синтаксис файла .htaccess или наличие в нем неподдерживаемых директив. Чаще всего достаточно закомментировать директиву Options (для этого нужно поставить в начале строки решетку — #), и проблема исчезнет.
>
> Ошибка 500 также может возникать вследствие неправильного обращения с CGI-скриптами:
>
> CGI-скрипты должны иметь окончания строк в формате UNIX (`\n`), а не в формате Windows (`\r\n`). Для этого их надо загружать на сервер по FTP в режиме ASCII.
>
> CGI-скрипты и папки, в которых они находятся, должны быть доступны для записи только владельцу, то есть иметь права `0755` (`drwxr-xr-x`).
>
> В результате работы CGI-скрипта сформированны неправильные HTTP-заголовки ответа. В этом случае для решения проблемы полезно обратиться к `error_log` (его можно найти в контрольной панели в разделе « Статистика / Лог-файлы / Лог ошибок»).

Comment: Я знаю почему возникают ошибки 500. Меня интересует вопрос как настроить сервер чтобы он выдавал ошибки PHP а не сервера.

Answer (score -1):

А что говорит error.log веб сервера. Один из вариантов, скрипт не выполняется из-за не правильно выставленных прав доступа.

Comment: Все выполняется, но если есть специально вызванная ошибка, то сервер выдает 500 ошибку, а ошибка PHP не показывается.